# Не отображается загруженная картинка в Recycler через Picasso

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, picasso

**Есть такой главный экран**

[image: Список фото]

При долгом нажатие на одну из картинок запускается код который сохраняет эту картинку через битмап пикассо вот так

```
public void savePhotoFromInternet(String url, String idImage) {
        Picasso.get()
                .load(url)
                .into(new Target() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                        imageCache.savePhoto(bitmap, idImage);
                        Log.d("Log", "МАПИМ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onBitmapFailed: ОШИБКА" + getClass().getSimpleName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPrepareLoad: Готовимся");
                    }
                });

    }
```

Более детально к  методу **imageCache.savePhoto(bitmap, idImage);**

```
public void savePhoto(Bitmap bitmap, String idImage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "saveImage: сохранение image в хранилище телефона в папке " + APP_FOLDER + " под именем " + idImage);

        getImageDir().mkdirs();
        File imageFile = new File(getImageDir(), idImage + ".png");


        if (!getImageDir().exists() && !getImageDir().mkdirs()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail");
        }

        try {
            //Открываем поток для записи файла
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

И в чем заключается беда, 1 к 10 из картинок может "сохраниться" во так (на примере 2 плохо загруженные картинки)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда такое происходит в логах видно что он запускает метод "**onPrepareLoad**" в **savePhotoFromInternet** > **.into(new Target()** после этого никаких телодвижений.... , что может быть не так?

Comment: Попробуйте задебажить и посмотреть куда он ведет